# record and stop recording functionality on the same button in the React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple react js application in which I have two buttons, record and stop.Everything is working fine. Now what I am trying to do is there should be only one button, if its not clicked, it should show record audio, and when i click on that button it should show stop and it should start recording an audio. I tried to do this with Nullish coalescing operator but couldn't find a way. Someone please help!
Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MicRecorder from 'mic-recorder-to-mp3';

const Mp3Recorder = new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 });

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     isRecording: false,
     blobURL: '',
     isBlocked: false,
   };
 }

 start = () => {
   if (this.state.isBlocked) {
     console.log('Permission Denied');
   } else {
     Mp3Recorder
       .start()
       .then(() => {
         this.setState({ isRecording: true });
       }).catch((e) => console.error(e));
   }
 };

 stop = () => {
   Mp3Recorder
     .stop()
     .getMp3()
     .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
       const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
       this.setState({ blobURL, isRecording: false });
     }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
 };

 componentDidMount() {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
     () => {
       console.log('Permission Granted');
       this.setState({ isBlocked: false });
     },
     () => {
       console.log('Permission Denied');
       this.setState({ isBlocked: true })
     },
   );
 }

 render(){
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
         <button onClick={this.start} disabled={this.state.isRecording}>Record</button>
         <button onClick={this.stop} disabled={!this.state.isRecording}>Stop</button>
         <audio src={this.state.blobURL} controls="controls" />
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change all the required properties on the button when the `isRecording` variable changes. That way you don't need to disable the button and the method will change.

```
<button onClick={() => { this.state.isRecording ? this.stop() : this.start()}}>{this.state.isRecording ? "Stop" : "Record"}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use short circuit evaluation to render different buttons based on the condition: -

```
render(){
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
       {!this.state.isRecording && 
         (
          <button onClick={this.start}>Record</button>
         );
       }
         
       {this.state.isRecording && 
         (
         <button onClick={this.stop}>Stop</button>
         );
       }
         
         <audio src={this.state.blobURL} controls="controls" />
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
```